# overloaded "operator++" returns a non const, and clang-tidy complains

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, postfix-operator, clang-tidy

I have just got the following warning from clang-tidy:

```
overloaded "operator++" returns a non-constant object 
 instead of a constant object type
```

https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cert-dcl21-cpp.html

Unfortunately the link which they are providing there does not work and https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682 has no easy way to find exactly this rule (seemingly the DCL rules start from 50).

But regardless where I look in the standard (for ex 16.5.7 Increment and decrement [over.inc]), I find no reference that postfix `operator ++` should return a const:

```
struct X {
    X operator++(int); // postfix a++
};
```

Question: is just clang-tidy overly protective, erroneous or why would I want to declare the return type of the postfix to be const?

Comment: Note: I logged a bug for this in the past, no reaction yet: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41842

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's clang-tidy trying to stop you from writing code that accomplishes nothing:

```
(x++)++; // Did we just increment a temporary?
```

Such forms of overloading *may* be useful, but not usually for postfix `++`. You have two options:

1. Do as clang-tidy says, but then maybe lose the benfeits of move semantics.
2. lvalue ref-qualify the overload instead, to mimic the little ints.

   ```
   X operator++(int) &; // Can't apply to rvalues anymore.
   ```

Option 2 is superior; prevents those silly mistakes, and retains move semantics if applicable.

Comment: Oddly, Carnegie-Mellon seem to have changed their mind about this guideline, since it no longer exists [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682).

Comment: @Useless - In C++03 that's the only way to prevent this mistake (and there are no move semantics to worry about). I guess they updated it to be with accordance with contemporary C++?

Comment: Probably. It's a pity they chose to break all the incoming links rather than leaving a note to that effect.

Comment: I wanted to say option 2 breaks `foo(returnsX()++);`, but then it feels kinda like a long shot.

Comment: @PasserBy - It should break. Assuming `X++` behaves as expected, and returns a copy of the old value, it compiles, but is broken already. `foo` doesn't see the updated value.

Comment: I applied option 2 in C++11, but clang-tidy still complains!

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - Of course it still complains. Option 1 is **to do as clang-tidy says** to blindly follow DCL21-CPP. Option 2 is not to do it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think it would be helpful if you'd mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: The best option here is to disable this obsolete rule in your clang-tidy config. Trying to follow it will likely trigger other contradictory clang-tidy rules.

Comment: Option 1 will give another clang-tidy error `Clang-tidy readability: avoid const value return`